# Bluemix development with Watson services and high availability design

Tags: jakarta-ee, websphere, ibm-cloud, high-availability, ibm-watson

We are going to build an application in IBM's Bluemix leveraging Watson analytics services. Is it possible to build it in "high-availability" mode? Any experience?

In an owned environment to achieve HA I would build a J2EE application based on an highly availablie server like a WAS-ND and deploy on a cluster with a clustered DB in the backend. Since I want to use Watson services I need to develop on bluemix. How is that done on bluemix? What should I use and deploy on top of?

Comment: please be a more elaborate about your problem

Comment: In an owned environment to achieve HA I would build a J2EE application based on an highly availablie server like a WAS-ND and deploy on a cluster with a clustered DB in the backend. Since I want to use Watson services I need to develop on bluemix. How is that done on bluemix? What should I use and deploy on top of?

Answer (score 2):

To reach the goal to provide to your user an application in high availability,  Bluemix  allows you  to create multiple instances of the same app.
If one instance crashes, traffic is automatically routed to the remaining instances, and the crashed instance is automatically restarted as quickly as possible.
In  case one particular  machine (DEA) that is hosting application instances crashes, the platform will automatically and transparently migrate any affected application instances to a different machine.
Recommendation is to define at least 3 instances.

If high availability of your application is particularly important, we also suggest to follow Blue green deployment  release technique : you can have your application running independently in multiple Bluemix regions, and create a custom fail-over and/or load-balancing solution across these regions.